# ftp upload/download in c# for windows mobile 6.5 with opencf.net.ftp

Tags: c#, ftp, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I tried to make an ftp upload and download but it is going all time to `Nullreference` error. It can be that the `opennetcf.net.ftp` is not the best way to solve the problem? Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

```cs
namespace ftp_load
{



    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public class FTPManagerClass
        {
            private static string password = "";
            private static string username = "";
            private static string host = "";

            private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
            private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
            private Stream ftpStream = null;
            // private int bufferSize = 2048;

            public FTPManagerClass(string user, string pass, string hostname)
            {
                username = user;
                password = pass;
                host = hostname;

            }

            public void DownloadFile(string remoteFile, string localFIle)
            {
                try
                {
                    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
                    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                    //ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                    ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                    ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(localFIle, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

                    fs.Close();
                    ftpStream.Close();
                    ftpResponse.Close();
                    ftpRequest = null;


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
            }

            public void UploadFile(string localFile, string remoteFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
                    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                    //  ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                    // ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                    ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
                    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                    ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
                    FileStream lfs = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open);
                    byte[] bytebuffer = new byte[lfs.Length];
                    int bytesSend = lfs.Read(bytebuffer, 0, (int)lfs.Length);
                    try
                    {

                        while (bytesSend != -1)
                        {
                            ftpStream.Write(bytebuffer, 0, bytesSend);
                            bytesSend = lfs.Read(bytebuffer, 0, (int)lfs.Length);

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    ftpResponse.Close();
                    ftpStream.Close();
                    lfs.Close();
                    ftpRequest = null;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }

        FTPManagerClass client;
        private static string password = "";
        private static string username = "";
        private static string host = "";

        private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
        private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
        private Stream ftpStream = null;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connMgr = new ConnMgr();
            connMgr.StatusChanged += new ConnMgr.StatusChangedEventHandler(StatusChanged_Handler);
        }
        private ConnMgr connMgr;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_br_down.Text != "")
            {
                client.DownloadFile(@"/GP_FTP/ans.txt", @"/download");
                client = new FTPManagerClass("usr", "pwd", "ftp://ftp.tzf.com");
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ures mezo");
            }
        }






        private void txt_br_dw_1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

The GPRS connection builds up, but after the ftp connection has some problem:

```cs
        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_login_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!connMgr.Connected)
            {
                connMgr.Connect("pannon", ConnMgr.ConnectionMode.Synchronous, " ", " ", "net");
                txtLog.Text += "Sync connection successful\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No connection!");
            }
  }

        private void txtLog_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void StatusChanged_Handler(object sender, ConnMgr.StatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            connMgr.Timeout = 3000;
            txtLog.Text += e.desc + "\r\n";         // Show current state's description

            if (!connMgr.Waiting)
                if (connMgr.Connected)
                    txtLog.Text += "Confirmed - We are now connected\r\n";
                else
                {
                    txtLog.Text += "Confirmed - Connection instance has been released\r\n";
                    // btnCancel.Enabled = false;
                    // btnConnect.Enabled = true;
                }

            if (e.connstatus == ConnMgr.ConnectionStatus.ExclusiveConflict)
                MessageBox.Show("If using Activesync, check connection settings for 'Allow wireless connection ...' or remove from homebase.");
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

No it looks the  authentication is ok.There is no problem!

I made this:

```cs
  try
                {
                  client = new FTPManagerClass("usr", "pwd", "ftp://ftp.tzf.com");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Login"+ ex);
                }
```

This is ok!

But after this: `ctacke`

```cs
            try 

            {
                MessageBox.Show("before download");
               client.DownloadFile("/GP_FTP/ans.txt", "/download");
               MessageBox.Show("after download");
            }

            catch (Exception ex1)

            {


                MessageBox.Show("file"+ ex1);

            }
```

The problem is now : In `client.DownloadFile` `System.nullreferenceException`
Now i have no idea :(.
it can be some pity thing...

Why this is null? `client.DownloadFile(@"/GP_FTP/ans.txt", @"/download");`
i tried `client.DownloadFile("/GP_FTP/ans.txt", "/download");` and `client.DownloadFile("ans.txt", "/download");`
and the same. WHY?

Comment: Thanks Gilles for the editing!

Comment: Where in all of this code is the NullReferenceException happening?

Comment: `client.DownloadFile(@"/GP_FTP/ans.txt", @"/download");`

Answer (score 0):

This won't work:

```
client.DownloadFile(@"/GP_FTP/ans.txt", @"/download");
client = new FTPManagerClass("usr", "pwd", "ftp://ftp.tzf.com");
```

You can't perform operations on a variable if you have not assigned something to it yet - then you get a `NullReferenceException`. The `new` bit goes first:

```
client = new FTPManagerClass("usr", "pwd", "ftp://ftp.tzf.com");
client.DownloadFile(@"/GP_FTP/ans.txt", @"/download");
```

Specifying the ftp address and sending the username, password *before* trying to download the file should make more sense, too.

Comment: I tried to take a login to another button and after to connect( write to textbox ) to FTP tried to download-upload but all time going to `Null reference exception`. I think the problem is not there!

Comment: There could be multiple problems here - does the `NullReferenceException` still occur at `client.DownloadFile(@"/GP_FTP/ans.txt", @"/download");`?

Comment: Yes i think the problem is there because the FTP connection builds up. I don't know what can be the other soultion for download file if this not works.

Comment: @user5494221 a `NullReferenceException` is a simple error in an application, which has nothing to do with the technology you use for downloading a file. Some variable somewhere is not assigned to what you expect it to be assigned to.

Comment: Thx ´C.Evenhuis´ but i could not find where! :)